Unexpected Token Error: Handling 404 Response in NextJS Application
Unexpected Token Error: Handling 404 Response in NextJS Application
GET /chat 404 in 1ms
 ⨯ Error [SyntaxError]: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (file:///Users/prathamchauhan/Documents/Next-Projects/chat-with-pdf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js:1:657096)
    at successSteps (file:///Users/prathamchauhan/Documents/Next-Projects/chat-with-pdf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js:1:657096)
    at eval (file:///Users/prathamchauhan/Documents/Next-Projects/chat-with-pdf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js:1:657096)
    at <unknown> (node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7)
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:206:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
 ⨯ Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot append headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.appendHeader (node:_http_outgoing:759:11)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
digest: "3422819266"
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
 ✓ Compiled in 365ms (3043 modules)
 GET /chat 404 in 1ms
 ⨯ Error [SyntaxError]: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (file:///Users/prathamchauhan/Documents/Next-Projects/chat-with-pdf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js:1:657096)
    at successSteps (file:///Users/prathamchauhan/Documents/Next-Projects/chat-with-pdf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js:1:657096)
    at eval (file:///Users/prathamchauhan/Documents/Next-Projects/chat-with-pdf/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/edge-runtime/index.js:1:657096)
    at <unknown> (node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7)
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:206:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
 ⨯ Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot append headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.appendHeader (node:_http_outgoing:759:11)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
digest: "3422819266"

/chat/page.tsx
    import { checkPdf } from '@/src/actions/existingPdf'
    import ChatComponent from '@/src/components/ChatComponent'
    import { authOptions } from '@/src/lib/auth'
    import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
    import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
    import React from 'react'

    const page = async() => {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
    if(!session){
        redirect("/")
    }
    const response = await checkPdf()
    return (
    <div>
       <ChatComponent name={session.user.name} heading={response===true?true:false}/>
    </div>
    )
    }

    export default page

    "use server"
    import { getServerSession } from "next-auth"
    import { authOptions } from "../lib/auth"
    import fs from "fs";
    import prisma from "@/db";
    import { CloseVectorNode } from "@langchain/community/vectorstores/closevector/node";
    import { embeddings } from "../constants/embeddings";


    export async function checkPdf(){
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
    if(session.user){
      const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: Number(session.user.id)
        }
      }) 
    
      console.log("uuid: ",user?.uuid)
      const loadedVectorStore = await CloseVectorNode.loadFromCloud({
        uuid:user?.uuid || "",
        embeddings,
        credentials: {
          key: process.env.VOYAGE_ACCESS_KEY,
          secret: process.env.VOYAGE_SECRET,
        },
      });

    // Check if the directory exists
    if (user?.uuid && user.uuid.trim().length>0) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
    }
    return false
    
    }

